# Need help in this unix command

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to fetch the latest file in a directory and get the time since it is modified. Using the below command but getting error. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? 
And is there any simplified version for this?

```
NOW=`date +%s`;
FILE=`ls -lpt /tmp/app/test/*.txt | head -n 1 | awk '{print $9}'`;
Time=`stat -c %Y ${FILE}`;
DIFF=`${NOW} - ${Time}`;
echo ${DIFF}
```

-bash: 1552214130: command not found

Comment: `${NOW} - ${Time}` this is just a calculation. With backquotes you are trying to execute the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
DIFF=`${NOW} - ${Time}`;
```

Backticks mean to execute what's contained as a command, and then substitute the output into the command. So this will try to use the value of `${NOW}` as the name of a command to execute. But it's just a numeric timestamp, not a command.

In order to perform calculations in `bash` use `$(( expression ))`, not backticks.

```
DIFF=$((NOW - Time))
```

BTW, you should not use all-capital names for your variables. By convention those are reserved for environment variables.